# Finding the Inverse of a Matrix using Row Operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Problem:
Let $A$ be the following matrix. Find $A^{-1}$.
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{bmatrix} $$
Answer:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 13 & 18 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 22 & 30 & 7 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
Now I multiply the second row by $-22$ and the third row by $13$.
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 13(-22) & 18(-22) &- 88 & -22 & 0 \\
 0 & 22(13) & 390 & 91 & 0 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 13(-22) & 18(-22) &- 88 & -22 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 390 - 18(22) & 91 - 88 & -22 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -286 & -396 & -88 & -22 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -6 & 3 & -22 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -286 & -396 & -88 & -22 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
Now we multiply the third row by $396$ and add it to the second row.
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -286 & 0 & -88 -198 & -22 + \frac{396(11)}{2} & -\frac{396(13)}{6} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -286 & 0 & -286 & 2156 & -858 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{2156}{286} & \dfrac{858}{286} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{98}{13} & \dfrac{66}{13} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
Now we need to work on the first row.
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 0 & 3 & 1 & \dfrac{2(98)}{13} & \dfrac{-2(66)}{13} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{98}{13} & \dfrac{66}{13} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 0 & 3 & 1 & \dfrac{196}{13} & -\dfrac{132}{13} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{98}{13} & \dfrac{66}{13} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
I have reason to believe the correct answer is:
$$  \begin{bmatrix}
 -\dfrac{1}{2} & 1 & -\dfrac{1}{2} \\
 1 & -5 & 3 \\
 -\dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{11}{3} & -\dfrac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} $$
As such I am confident I made a mistake. Where did I go wrong?

Based upon the feed back I got I updated my solution. Here is an updated but still wrong solution.

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 7 & 8 & 9 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 13 & 18 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 22 & 30 & 7 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
Now I multiply the second row by $-22$ and the third row by $13$.
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 13(-22) & 18(-22) &- 88 & -22 & 0 \\
 0 & 22(13) & 390 & 91 & 0 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 13(-22) & 18(-22) &- 88 & -22 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 390 - 18(22) & 91 - 88 & -22 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -286 & -396 & -88 & -22 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -6 & 3 & -22 & 13 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -286 & -396 & -88 & -22 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
Now we multiply the third row by $396$ and add it to the second row.
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -286 & 0 & -88 -198 & -22 + \frac{396(11)}{2} & -\frac{396(13)}{6} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -286 & 0 & -286 & 2156 & -858 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{2156}{286} & \dfrac{858}{286} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{98}{13} & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
Now we need to work on the first row.
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 0 & 3 & -1 & -\dfrac{ 98}{26} & -6 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{98}{13} & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & -3 & 1 & \dfrac{ 49}{13} & 6 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{98}{13} & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 -\frac{3}{2} & \dfrac{ 49}{13} + 3 & 6 - \frac{3(13)}{6} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{98}{13} & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 9 & - \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{98}{13} & 3 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{13}{6} \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: When I was looking for mistakes in my work, I found that finding prime numbers in my denominators that shouldn't have been there usually did not bode well. Question the steps where those prime numbers came from.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you so much for this comment. This will help me too; I often mald a lot when it comes to silly mistakes and I love learning about these types of tricks to recognise mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited answer: Firstly, in the step 'first we multiply the second row by 396...', the second last entry should be $-22 + 396 (\frac{11}{3})$ (rather than $\frac{11}{2}$).

Then, after this, there was the error that I pointed out in my first answer: $\frac{858}{286} = 3$, rather than $\frac{66}{13}$.

This should sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Given that :
$$=\begin{pmatrix}-1&2&3&1&0&0\\ 4&5&6&0&1&0\\ 7&8&9&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Row Operation 1 : multiply the first row by $-1$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&-3&-1&0&0\\ 4&5&6&0&1&0\\ 7&8&9&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Row Operation 2 : add $-4$ times the first row to the second row
$$=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&-3&-1&0&0\\ 0&13&18&4&1&0\\ 7&8&9&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Row Operation 3 : add $-7$ times the first row to the third row
$$=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&-3&-1&0&0\\ 0&13&18&4&1&0\\ 0&22&30&7&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Row Operation 4 : multiply the second row by $\frac{1}{13}$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&-3&-1&0&0\\ 0&1&\frac{18}{13}&\frac{4}{13}&\frac{1}{13}&0\\ 0&22&30&7&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Row Operation 5 : add $-22$ times the second row to the third row
$$=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&-3&-1&0&0\\ 0&1&\frac{18}{13}&\frac{4}{13}&\frac{1}{13}&0\\ 0&0&-\frac{6}{13}&\frac{3}{13}&-\frac{22}{13}&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Row Operation 6 : multiply the third row by $-\frac{13}{6}$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&-3&-1&0&0\\ 0&1&\frac{18}{13}&\frac{4}{13}&\frac{1}{13}&0\\ 0&0&1&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{11}{13}&-\frac{13}{6}\end{pmatrix}$$
Row Operation 7 : add $-\frac{18}{13}$ times the third row to the second row
$$=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&-3&-1&0&0\\ 0&1&0&1&-5&3\\ 0&0&1&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{11}{13}&-\frac{13}{6}\end{pmatrix}$$
Row Operation 8 : add 3 times the third row to the first row
$$=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&0&-\frac{5}{2}&11&-\frac{13}{2}\\ 0&1&0&1&-5&3\\ 0&0&1&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{11}{13}&-\frac{13}{6}\end{pmatrix}$$
Row Operation 9 : add 2 times the second row to the first row
$$=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&-\frac{1}{2}&1&-\frac{1}{2}\\ 0&1&0&1&-5&3\\ 0&0&1&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{11}{13}&-\frac{13}{6}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: While doing calculations, if we separate the entries of A & I by some vertical line like $[A | I]$, and in the subsequent matrices, then the calculations will be more readable and mistakes can be avoided as well.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that $A:=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & 3\\ 4 & 5 & 6\\  7 & 8 &9\end{bmatrix}$ implies $\det(A)=6\not=0$ so indeed $A^{-1}$ there exists. Using row operarations $\sim$ we need to find $A^{-1}$ such that $[A|I]\sim [I|A^{-1}]$ with $I$ identity matrix of order $3$.

\begin{align*}
[A| I]&:=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} -1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 7 & 8 & 9  & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right]\sim \cdots \sim \left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 &  -\frac{1}{2} & 1 & -\frac{1}{2}\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -5 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{11}{3} &-\frac{13}{6} \end{array}\right]:=[I|A^{-1}]
\end{align*}
where the row operations $\sim \cdots \sim$ in this case is given by

- $R_{2}\longleftrightarrow R_{2}+4R_{1}$.
- $R_{2} \longleftrightarrow R_{3}+7R_{1}$.
- $R_{3} \longleftrightarrow R_{3}-\frac{22}{13}R_{2}$.
- $R_{3} \longleftrightarrow \frac{-13}{6}R_{3}$.
- $R_{2} \longleftrightarrow R_{2}-\frac{18}{13}R_{3}$.
- $R_{1} \longleftrightarrow R_{1}+3R_{3}$.
- $R_{1} \longleftrightarrow R_{1}+2R_{2}$.

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computational_efficiency for to see the computational efficiency about the Gaussian elimination.